# Adding a Custom Attribute (Extension) in B2C using Azure AD Graph API doesn't show up in Azure Portal User Attributes blade

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007683/b2c-custom-attributes-not-showing-when-created-using-graph-api-directory-schema) and remains unanswered. I can add a custom attribute as follows:

```
{
    "name": "new_secure_claim",
    "dataType": "Boolean",
    "targetObjects": ["User"]
}
```

I post this data to the Azure AD Graph API end point with needed headers: 
`https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/applications/{objectId of b2c-extensions-app}/extensionProperties?api-version=1.6`. I get a response with the extension just created. I can even see the extension when I query the graph to get all extensions for the `b2c-extensions-app` (notice the top one below):

```
{
"odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/melangeauth.onmicrosoft.com/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.ExtensionProperty",
"value": [{
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.ExtensionProperty",
        "objectType": "ExtensionProperty",
        "objectId": "b7a36f93-8d7a-463f-8d3e-88f449243ea6",
        "deletionTimestamp": null,
        "appDisplayName": "",
        "name": "extension_8588c037999f4d058cc08e2e5f99de30_new_secure_claim",
        "dataType": "Boolean",
        "isSyncedFromOnPremises": false,
        "targetObjects": ["User"]
    }, {
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.ExtensionProperty",
        "objectType": "ExtensionProperty",
        "objectId": "b6c6d55f-21a8-4403-a68f-f858966077bf",
        "deletionTimestamp": null,
        "appDisplayName": "",
        "name": "extension_8588c037999f4d058cc08e2e5f99de30_manager_admin_authorization",
        "dataType": "Boolean",
        "isSyncedFromOnPremises": false,
        "targetObjects": ["User"]
    }, {
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.ExtensionProperty",
        "objectType": "ExtensionProperty",
        "objectId": "2642596f-5706-47fb-abdb-6d0d012a3006",
        "deletionTimestamp": null,
        "appDisplayName": "",
        "name": "extension_8588c037999f4d058cc08e2e5f99de30_manager_admin",
        "dataType": "Boolean",
        "isSyncedFromOnPremises": false,
        "targetObjects": ["User"]
    }, {
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.ExtensionProperty",
        "objectType": "ExtensionProperty",
        "objectId": "ee2c66e3-ced4-4bc8-90d5-e2b18690a56b",
        "deletionTimestamp": null,
        "appDisplayName": "",
        "name": "extension_8588c037999f4d058cc08e2e5f99de30_manager_ads_admin",
        "dataType": "Boolean",
        "isSyncedFromOnPremises": false,
        "targetObjects": ["User"]
    }
]
}
```

But, when I go to the "Azure AD B2C/User attributes" blade in my B2C directory in the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin/TenantManagementMenuBlade/manageUserAttributes), I cannot see that extension attribute. I also cannot see it when I go to add claims to return for a policy.

What do I need to do differently in the adding of a custom extension to the b2c-extensions-app application in order for me to see if in the Azure portal User attributes blade?

Comment: Seems like they are doing something special in the portal we can't do via the AD Graph API.  Do you have a lot of custom attributes?  Why not just create them manually?

Comment: I wanted developers to tag pieces of the app with claims and then the app would add those claims via reflection to the directory - at which point new claims could be assigned to users.

Comment: Interesting!  After reading the answer, that makes total sense.  The claims have to get into the xml based policies...

Answer (score 1):

Well, hmm.

It gets complicated when people things in an undocumented way. For sake of simplicity I would encourage you to stay with defining your extensions with the portal. If you just want to do that (and seems you want). Because there is much more than just registering an extension with the Graph.

To understand why is that, you have to more deeply understand how B2C ticks from the inside. You get overview when you dive into [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom). However custom policies are, as it stays in the docs, for identity pros who know what are they doing. Straight to the point, the `claims schema` is defined in so called base policy. It is not just defined in the Graph, but also `backed` in the base policy. There is XML schema which dictates what a B2C must do and how it should do it. And all the claims (and custom attributes) are also defined in that schema. So when you change something regarding this schema in the portal (adding new attribute), it is registered with the Graph API, but it is also updated in the claims definition schema, which is kept separately.

That's why when you manually register an extension with the Graph it just does not show up in the portal.

I do not expect that you jump and begin learning Custom policies, because for your case you just do not need them. But I hope that having to define your custom attributes in the portal is not a big of an issue for you.

Comment: That really doesn't answer my question but guesses at why things don't work. It would have been better as a 'comment' instead of an 'answer'. I can envision the graph API behind the scenes actually updating the default policy XML as the portal blade does.

Comment: It is too lo g for a comment and  I am confident that this is also pretty close to the situation.